# Select Option Over Flow the Web Page When Text More Than 200 Character

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, html-select

This Select Control Overflow the webpage
as Shown
[image]

```
<div>
  <select id="animalName">
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elitAenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec qu</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

I want to ellipsis, crop or divide it to multilines when select option overflow the page using **CSS not JavaScript**
[image]

Note:
I tried this css and it not works

```
option{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If only the selected option needs to be truncated, the `text-overflow:ellipsis` works on `select` (but not on `option` for now: Styling for form elements are pretty limited depends on different browsers and OS.)

```html
<select style="width: 200px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" id="animalName">
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elitAenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec qu</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
```

If all options needs to be truncated in the opened dropdown menu, you would need to implement the dropdown menu while avoiding these form elements. Since you're using bootstrap 4, you can simply use bootstrap's `dropdown` class combined with the [text-truncate](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow) class: (The width of the opened dropdown menu to be truncated could be adjusted as shown.)

```
<div class="dropdown" style="width: 200px;">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="asdf" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 300px;">
        <a class="dropdown-item text-truncate" href="#">Hamster</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-truncate" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetuer adipiscing elitAenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec qu link</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-truncate" href="#">Goldfish</a>
    </div>
</div>
```